# Creating a trigger that will update an attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Question: write a trigger that will update the invoice subtotal each time the line table is updated (a new row inserted, updated or deleted). Include the SQL statements used to test the insert, update and delete.

I'm finding it difficult to properly understand triggers and I don't know why. I understand the basic concept of it (at least I think I do) but I can't seem to understand how to answer my question. The following code is my attempt at answering the above question:

```
create or replace trigger update_subtotal
after insert or update or delete 
on invoice
for each row

begin

insert into line ('inv_number', 'line_number', 'p_code', 'line_units', 'line_price')
values ('1009', '3', '12345-6t', '1', '123.45');

end;

select * from line;
```

After running this code I ended up with these errors:

```
Errors: TRIGGER UPDATE_SUBTOTAL
Line/Col: 3/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 3/19 PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
Line/Col: 17/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"
```

I'm using Oracle Live.

In short: help.

Comment: It sounds like there are two tables, one for the invoice and one for the line items.  You haven't shown us what those tables actually look like.  Help us help you with a test case-- show us how to create the tables and what data you have.  If you're using Oracle LiveSQL, send us a link to what you're working on so we can see it for ourselves.

Comment: [https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:5549403073560:::43:P43_ID:254005220510359660134221650004558874280]  @JustinCave Here is a link to the script file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the concept backwards.  The `invoice` table needs to be updated when `line` changes -- so `line` needs the trigger and the change to `invoice` is an `update`.  That would be something like this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_line_update_subtotal
after insert or update or delete 
on line
for each row
begin
    update invoice i
        set total = coalesce(i.total, 0) +
                    coalesce(:new.line_Units * :new.line_price, 0) -
                    coalesce(:old.line_Units * :old.line_price, 0)
        where i.inv_number = coalesce(:new.inv_number, :old.inv_number);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. When I run this code I end up with this error: Errors: TRIGGER TRG_LINE_UPDATE_SUBTOTAL
Line/Col: 4/9 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following: (begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
   json_object json_array

Comment: @yshaikh20x: There was a semicolon too many and some zeros missing. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works now. I just need do my tests and I'll be all done!